Space anime with a spaceship get boarded by aliens. One of the crew gets stuck in a jellyfish-like alien creature
As a kid I saw an anime which was way more scarier than Starzinger (and other space animes which was shown on tv at that time), taking place in space. I do not remember if it was a show or movie, all I can remember was that they were in a spaceship and they got borded by an alien force. 
I remember that one of the crew-members got stuck suffocating in a "jelly"-ish alien form and the crew were really unaware about their unwelcome visitors. 
Got any clue where this could be from? This happened between 1992-1996, but the anime could be older. What fascinated me was the feeling the flick managed to create about being borded by an unknown alien force. It was in English and I suspect the jelly-form wasn't the aliens true shape.

This was between 1992-1996, the movie/show could be older, though. I think it was adult-oriented and it was probably in English. The thing I remember and what fascinated me was the scary feeling of an unknown alien force on the ship. Problem is that's the only thing I remember (and the Jelly-form which I don't think was the actual aliens real shape).

Do you remember what channel you saw it on?

No, I really don't. I suspect it was recorded from a Swedish channel called "TV3".

Gall Force Eternal Story


 (at 7:20)

I believe it to be this as, aside from it being in space and having the infiltration (jelly) suit, this was shown on the Sci-fi channel in America in the mid-90's, which is where I watched it for the first time.

I am impressed! Allthough it is not precisely as I remember it (a little bit too cheerful and less dark) this must be the flick. Thanks!

Lily C.A.T., 1987 Japanese Anime.
An anime knockoff combination of The Thing and Alien.  A crew of people on a large spaceship are traveling to a distant world.  While they're in cryo-sleep (no light speed drive in this universe, so it takes decades to get there), the ship picks up an alien space pod, which somehow gets into the water supply, dissolves, and starts eating/infecting the ship.  The crew wake up, and one by one, they either disappear or get infected by the alien bacteria and die.  After a crew member dies, the creature dissolves their bodies and adds their mass to its own.  The creature can morph into different shapes, like The Thing.  It physically snatches a cat and some of the crew members.  Near the end, two bodies of the crew are shown enveloped in jelly-like pod appendages.  The anime tries to emphasize a creepy, realistic atmosphere like Alien, where the crew don't know what's going on.

I am fairly certain I saw this a while ago and concluded it wasn't the one. The scene with a guy stuck within a blob, is that present in Lily C.A.T.?

At 49:59, it shows a guy's dead body totally enveloped in a blob appendage.

It's a good shoot but I am fairly sure this isn't it. :) Rewatched Lily C.A.T. and allthough close the blob was just a blob which was standing in a space corridor with a suffocating human inside. This one is too fast and also too skinny. It wasn't a blob appendage, just a blob.

I was looking for the same movie since yesterday and I think I found it:
Roots Search - 1986




I think its Wonder Beat Scramble

Aliens from the planet Vijure are on a quest for a key to the secret of life and toward this end infiltrate human bodies. Such incursions often have grave consequences and the White Pegasus Team is commissioned to fight the invaders. They track the aliens on the ship Wonder Beat. The main character is the fourteen-year-old Susumu Sugita, a White Pegasus Team operative who was deployed on that mission under clandestine circumstances.

